# Can we remove environment.ts file from Angular project?

Tags: angular, typescript, environment-variables

I have environment.ts and environment.prod.ts file in my angular web project.

I know that environment.ts is the default configuration for any project.
I want to rename it to environment.dev.ts, but I m facing a lot of errors.

After research, i found that in Angular v6, we do something like:

```
 "fileReplacements": [
     {
       "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
       "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
     }
```

after seeing this, I think environment.ts file is compulsory and I should create a new file environment.dev.ts file and just replace it.

Can anyone tell the feasibility of the both the approaches ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `environment.ts` contains DEV configuration so there is no need to replace it. But, if the need arises, you can extend DEV build config in `angular.json` with file repacement for DEV build. Same for any other type of build specified in `angular.json`.

```javascript
"configurations": {
  "dev": {
    ...
    "fileReplacements": [{
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
    }]
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you leave the environment.ts and create a new configuration for the dev, so that when you call the development configuration, it takes the correct environment.

```
 "dev": {
         "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts".
             }]
         }
```